# Show $ \mathbb C^{n^2} $ Lie Group is Connected

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

Ok, so I am the matrix Lie group of invertible  $n^2 \times n^2 $ matrices is connected. Only approach I can think of is showing it's path connected and therefore connected.

Simplest path is the Complex straight line tz+(1-t)w between invertible matrices w to z. But how can

I show determinant is non-zero throughout the path? I know $Det(AB)=DetADetB$ but I don't know how to

deal with $Det(tz +(1-t)w)$ to show it's never 0. I guess since Det is a polynomial of degree n we

could alsways tweak the path at most n times  to avoid any roots we may run into. Is that enough

to show connectedness?